# What is a safe way to convert a full date time to a local date time

Tags: c#

I have a third party that sends me a `JSON` with a date value like this:

```
"1970-11-28T11:00:00.000-0500"
```

What's the correct way of converting it to a "DateOnly" - so not time - value that represent the date in my time zone?

Comment: Is the supplied date/time in your local timezone, in UTC or some other zone?

Comment: That's the part I am confused too. it has a -5 at the end so I think that's how they say what is time zone so looks like could be anything they specify in there ?

Comment: The -5 signifies 5 hours behind UTC. To convert to local time var localTime = DateTime.Parse("1970-11-28T11:00:00.000-0500").ToLocalTime()

Comment: @auburg oh so unlike its name, I think ToLocalTime is actually doing the DATE part and not the Time part ... I care about the date too so that should be good I think

Comment: FYI The format is I think iso 8601 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the input date/time like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(testDate, @"yyyy\-MM\-dd\THH\:mm\:ss\.fffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Which should handle the DateTime (which appears to be in ISO 8601 format)
You should then be able to get the local equivalent via .ToLocalTime()

Answer (score 1):

**The below example can also serve as a guide:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string getdate = "1970-11-28T11:00:00.000-0500";


        var dt = DateTime.Parse(getdate).ToLocalTime();

        string s = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //1970-11-28

    }
}
}
```