# Using Local Timestamp with Serilog MongoDb Sink

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog MongoDb Sink with ASP.NET Core 2.2. But I have a big problem. All my records are like that. Timestamps values and UtcTimesamps values are always the same. I couldn't find any solution to fix it. I want to use the localtime for timestamp. How can I do that?

```
"_id" : "5d1a6815e688ed7b7833d870"
"Timestamp": 2019-07-01T20:07:49.285+00:00
"Level": "Information"
"MessageTemplate": "Test"
"RenderedMessage": "Hello"
"Properties": ...
"UtcTimestamp": 2019-07-01 20:07:49Z
```

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56690638/7755751

Comment: @SamuelAkosile thank you for your respond. But I think I don't have problem about the DateTime value. It's about the MongoDb Sink for Serilog. I can't set the date. The date value sets from the sink.